# Deleting git history?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, gitlab

I went to commit to my repository today and forgot I hadn't saved all the files in Visual Studio, it was after I commited that I remembered, I never pushed my commit to the GitLab server using GitHub desktop but I did commit it to the point where I could push it.

I went to the history tab and it said I could revert my commit. Now its all messed up and my changes before the revert aren't showing up? Can anyone help with this? I just want to get back to the stage where I had  my changes and remove the fact I reverted my commit or commited in the first place.

I'm running in Windows 10 using Github Desktop.

I realize reverting the commit replaces all your changes in the last commit to the way the repository is at but I have a backup before reverting the commit and have applied this backup..

Comment: What did that revert tool actually do?  Did it do a `git revert`, or did it nuke some of your stuff?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not pushed yet to GitHub, that means you can reset/amend your current commit, instead of reverting them (adding a new commit).

Meaning: your last commit does not represent your saved files.
So, in command line, assuming you have a backup of your saved files in the state you want them:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git reset --hard origin/master
# apply your backup
git add .
git commit -m "the right commit"
git push
```

That will replace the last (wrong) commit by one which has your files with their proper (saved) content.